# Android https request not working in fragment

Tags: javascript, java, android, json

When I use a search function using the Kitsu API in my fragment [search fragment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udxDA.png) my app crashes and goes back to the main activity. While using Logcat I have seen that nothing is coming through and I don't know why it's crashing.[LogCat results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47wgU.png), [the code to initialize the https request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndDfS.png), [Code for my onPostexecution in my https request.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3I9U.png) And if you're wondering I'm using async task for my https request. After a bit of testing I have learned that it happens when I comment out the code for the https request, so there is something with the onClick Listener.

Answer (score 0):

How about if you change the code below?

```
MainActivity myMainActivity = new Activity();
```

to

```
MainActivity myMainActivity = getActivity();
```

Comment: Hello sir, sorry for wasting time, but I have found the solution to my problem by using a .OnclickListener instead of setting up an onClick in my layout for the button. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for wasting time, but I have found the solution to my problem by using a .OnclickListener instead of setting up an onClick in my layout for the button. Thank you very much